# Android - fixed size cells for tableLayout

Tags: android, imageview, tableview, invisible

Here is what im trying to do :

I want to create a table (or a grid) where each cell will contain an imageView,
I also want to make these imageViews dragable and maybe make some of them invisible at some point...

BUT

I dont want to make the imageView changes (location of visibility) affect the size of its row or column (thus changing the location of other imageViews). i.e when i make all the images in a certain row "invisible" the whole row resizes and stretching the other rows.

Basically i've tried everyThing , using tableView gave me the best results - but still not good enough...

This is how a basic Row looks like

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView00"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView01"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView02"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView03"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Is there a better way ? what am i doing wrong ?